# Tessaract gives poor results on Binary Image

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract, opencv3.0

I am trying to detect Alphabets in a picture using the tesseract library, which comes as an extra module for OpenCv3.
After a lot of preprocessing, I was able to get a very decent enough picture of the Alphabet.
However the tesserct library fails to recognise it at all.
[image]

Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/text/ocr.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::text;


Mat img=imread("result.jpg",0);
if(img.empty()){
    cout<<"Image not loaded!!\n";
    return 1;
}
string output_text;
vector<Rect> detected;
vector<string> list;
vector<float> conf;
Ptr<OCRTesseract> ocr = OCRTesseract::create();
ocr->run(img,output_text,&detected,&list,&conf,0);

for(int i=0; i<detected.size(); i++){
    Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,150);
    rectangle( img, detected[i].tl(), detected[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
}
//cout<<"x="<<detected[0].x<<" y="<<detected[0].y

cout<<"Text found is:\n"<<output_text<<endl;
imshow("My",img);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

People have said that Tesseract is my best option. However I am not getting any result with the same.
Here is the link to Tesseract Library Documentation for opencv3.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html#gsc.tab=0

Also, is there any difference between using the native Tesseract Lib vs OpenCV version ?

Comment: What if you get rid of the circle? Either fill the outside, or crop the image so that it's only a black letter on white background?

Comment: you can test your image [here](https://www.newocr.com/)

Comment: Try Tesseract's different [page segmentation modes](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html), for instance, 10 - for a single character.